# I want to delete items from dynamic div using a delete button inside it

Tags: javascript

// Create a row for the item in view

```
const order_item = document.createElement('div');
order_item.className = `ordered_item`;
order_item.innerHTML = `
    <div class="product-name">${item.namn}</div>
    <div class="product-percentage">${item.alkoholhalt}</div>
    <div class="product-price">${item.prisinklmoms}</div>
    <button class="btn-selected"  onclick="delOrderlist()">Del</button>
`;
orderContainer.appendChild(order_item);
```

This item is created dynamically and a button is there inside it. I want to delete the itemlist using this button.

Comment: Need suggestions to implement the deletion.

Comment: I am implementing using a const in javascript but unable to get the element of a button from div.                                                                                                                       
    const delOrderlist = () => {
    const removeDiv = document.getElementById('div-button');
   for(var i =0; i < removeDiv.length; i++) {
    var button = removeDiv[i]
    button.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
     var buttonClicked = event.target
     buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    })
   }
};

Comment: I've just seen your delete code. Could you put it in your question please as it's what you need us to look at. Also, it has errors, can you put the errors that you see on your browser's dev tools console into your question too, it'll help speed up the debugging. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add your HTML. This code:   const removeDiv = document.getElementById('div-button');
  for(var i =0; i <removeDiv.length; i++) { ...} makes no sense. You are selecting a single element and then iterating through it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is possibly some confusion between dealing with a **list** of orders and a **single** order.

Here is a snippet which deals with a single order. When an order's button is clicked you can pass the function the element (this). You can then find the parent of this element and remove it. In the given code there seemed to be an attempt to go through deleting a whole list, which is not what the deletion of a single order requires.

```js
const orderContainer = document.getElementById('orderContainer');

const order_item = document.createElement('div');

order_item.className = 'ordered_item';
order_item.innerHTML = '<div class="product-name">${item.namn}</div><div class="product-percentage">${item.alkoholhalt}</div><div class="product-price">${item.prisinklmoms}</div><button class="btn-selected"  onclick="delOrder(this)">Del</button>';
orderContainer.appendChild(order_item);

const delOrder = (el) => {
  el.parentElement.remove();
   }
```

```html
<div id="orderContainer"></div>
```